# Spring properties and idempotentKey in uri of a File endpoint

Tags: spring, apache-camel, endpoint, idempotent

I'm using a file endpoint to monitor changes on a file.

1. I need to be notified whenever the file is edited (i.e., the last-modified time changes)
2. I should specify the path of the file from properties, using Spring property placeholders

Everything works fine if I write:

```
<camelContext>
  <route>
    <from uri="file:/my/path?fileName=myFilename.txt&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}" />
    <log message="Received file: ${header.CamelFilePath} (${header.CamelFileLastModified})" />
    <to uri="direct:result" />
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

But if I change the code to use Spring properties, therefore creating an `<endpoint>`, it doesn't work anymore.

```
<camelContext>
  <endpoint id="fileEndpoint"
  uri="file://${ids.log.dir}?fileName=${ids.log.file}&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}" />

  <route id="fileRoute">
    <from ref="fileEndpoint" />
    <log message="Received file: ${header.CamelFilePath} (${header.CamelFileLastModified})" />
    <to uri="direct:result" />
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

I guess there is an issue with the `${}` notation and the `${file:...}` placeholders being expanded too early.

How can I resolve this issue? (I shall use Spring properties, not Camel's.) Is there any way to escape the `$`?

Answer (score 1):

Camel property placeholders is using `{{` and `}}` style. See more details at

- http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

And this FAQ:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Comment: You mean I could use `<endpoint uri="file://${log.dir}?fileName=${log.file}&amp;idempotentKey={{file:name}}-{{file:modified}}" />`? It doesn't work. Also, I cannot write `{{log.dir}}` and `{{log.file}}` because I have them only available as Spring properties.

Comment: I solved using `<endpoint uri="file://${log.dir}?fileName=${log.file}&amp;idempotentKey=$simple{file:name}-$simple{file:‌​modified}" />`, as explained [here](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) (_Using Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer together with the File component_).

Comment: @Claus, the second link is dead. Should we use [this](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_bridging_camel_property_placeholders_with_spring_xml_files) instead?